# How Do I refresh a DataGridView bound to an Access database table that was updated?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, ado.net

I have a desktop application project. On the entry page a `DataGridView` shows the existing items in the database. Now when I enter a new Item I want to insert it directly into the `DataGridView`. Meaning, I want to reload/refresh the `DataGridView`. My database is in MS Access.

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(conn))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Name from GroupDetails where comID='" + label1.Text + "'", con);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,Name from GroupDetails where comID='" + label1.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        //SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    con.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd;
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into GroupDetails (ID,Name) values(@ID,@Name)";
        // cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(i!=0)
        {
            dataGridGroup.DataSource = GetData();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[Note: When I use a SQL database then it works fine.]

Comment: Call whatever the method which loadn and binds the data to the grid within the form's save method, Which should refersh the grid

Comment: @Coder::This code is working when I use SQL Server. But When I use access database it working from 2nd time. Means, let I have to enter 5 data. ID's are 1,2,3,4,5. When I insert 1, it does not take any thing. When I entered 2 it shows 1's data. when i insert 3 it shows 2's data. That means it working from 2nd time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm going to be a bit obvios but u said: "let I have to enter 5 data. ID's are 1,2,3,4,5. When I insert 1, it does not take any thing. When I entered 2 it shows 1's data. when i insert 3 it shows 2's data. That means it working from 2nd time."

and i say: when you see a behavior like that immediately know that it's a **TIMING PROBLEM**.

in this specific case i think that if you close your connection first then call `GetData()` it should work:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    int i = 0;
    con.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd;
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into GroupDetails (ID,Name) values(@ID,@Name)";
        // cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();

        if(i!=0)
        {
            dataGridGroup.DataSource = GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @No Idea For Name:: Thank you for your answer. It works fine.